# Styles of buttons on win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi

i know there are some styles you can put on a button in C++ win32 exa. like BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON BS_RADIOBUTTON but i do not know all of them and also how would i go about making a user drawn button

Comment: I'm sure you mean "Win32 exe" could you please change your description so others can search efficiently? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the [reference of all button styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775951(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN (as usual). And [an overview of the Button control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678951(VS.85).aspx) in general.

To create an owner drawn button, you need to specify the `BS_OWNERDRAW` flag and pocess the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775923(VS.85).aspx) notification in the button parent window.

Answer (score 1):

And if you only want to tweak the button drawing algorithm, you should look at the [DrawThemeBackground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773289.aspx) API - that allows you to draw the button using the same visuals that the standard Windows Theme engine uses.

You do need to be careful to handle the case when theming is disabled (when OpenTheme fails) however - in that case you're on your own unfortunately.